# How to combine validation with select_for_update?

Tags: django, django-models, atomic

I am developing a billing/banking system. There are 2 models Account and Transaction. On Transaction creationg I want to validate that transaction amount < account balance. I use django-admin and DRF. In both cases user should see validation error messages. In current implementation user sees respones code 500. Is there better way to validate transaction after rows lock?

```py
class Account(models.Model):
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    src = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="out_transactions")  
    dst = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="in_transactions")  
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            Account.objects.select_for_update().filter(pk__in=[self.src.id, self.dst.id])

            if self.src.balance < self.amount:
                raise ValueError('Not enough balance')

            self.src.balance -= self.amount
            self.dst.balance += self.amount
            self.src.save()
            self.dst.save()
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return validation error to users, then you better handle it on DRF/views side. For example if you are using DRF's viewset, then override `perform_create` method -  wrap creation of transcation in try-except block, catch this `ValueError` and return 400 response:

```
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        try:
            instance = serializer.save()
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError(...)
```

BTW, it would be safer to raise/catch some custom exception here, rather than `ValueError`, so that we do not misreport "Not enough balance" in case of some other error condition.